# I don't understand why I'm getting this error: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'style/style.css'"

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm trying to load a CSS file into my [Streamlit](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit) project, but I keep getting the above error. I promise, everything looks OK.

I created a folder named "style" in the same directory as the app file *"brookfield.py"*. Inside this style folder, I created a CSS file with [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad) and named it "style.css".

I used the following code to load the *style.css* file:

```
#---- USE LOCAL CSS ----
def local_css(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        st.markdown(f"<style>{f.read()}</style>", unsafe_allow_html=True)

local_css("style/style.css")
```

Yet, I’m getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'style/style.css'
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Ronmi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 557, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "brookfield.py", line 33, in <module>
    local_css("style/style.css")
File "brookfield.py", line 30, in local_css
    with open(file_name) as f:
```

Comment: Does the file `style/style.css` exist? (Hint: it doesn't). Make sure that it's located where you / Python expect it to be. Remember that relative paths are relative to the CWD, not to the Python source file you write them in.

Comment: @Brian61354270  I'm 100% certain that style/style.css exist. running 'print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())' also confirms my CWD. yet the error persists

Comment: it is fine now. like I stated in the question, I had used notepad for the CSS file. I copied the code in the notepad file which I had saved as style.css, deleted the notepad file,  opened a new file in spyder IDE, pasted the code and saved it as the new style.css inside the style folder.  so basically, I replaced  the style.css (notepad) with the style.css (spyder). Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Relative pathing is not relative to the source file, but the [current working directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html) (CWD), therefore unable to find *style.css*.

First verify the CWD. You can do this by adding

```
import os
print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())
```

To your *brookefield.py* file and by running the Streamlit application (it'll get printed to the console).

I'm pretty sure *style/style.css* won't be present in the CWD. Move these over to the CWD location and try again.